# Cloning 2 similar elements in jquery without using a new div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form having 2 dropdowns and one textbox,i need to clone all of them at once limiting them to 5 divs and also incrementing the id or the name, i could do this using two different elements in one div but facing a problem with two same elements at a time as it takes the similar id for both. I used [Fiddle_Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UkzU3/)

My html code is:

```
<div id="elements">

<div id="Outer_00">
   <select name="Type" id="Type_00" disabled="disabled" class="edit">
 <option value="ArtistType"  selected="selected">Artist Type </option>
<option value="Singer">Singer</option>
<option value="Actor">Actor</option>
<option value="Fighter">Fighter</option>
<option value="Editor">Editor</option>
<option value="Writer">Writer</option>
</select>
&nbsp; &nbsp;   
<select name="ASubType" id="ASubType_00" disabled="disabled" class="edit">
<option value="Artist Sub-Type"  selected="selected">Artist Sub-Type</option>
 <option value="Actor" >-----Actor-----</option>
 <option value="Comedian" >Comedian</option>
 <option value="Hero" >Hero</option>
 <option value="Villain" >Villain</option>
  <option value="Supporting Cast" >Supporting Cast</option>
 <option value="Singer" >-----Singer-----</option>
<option value="Folk" >Folk</option>
 <option value="Pop" >Pop</option>
 <option value="Movie" >Movie</option>

 </select>
 &nbsp; &nbsp;
 <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" name="Quantity" id="Quantity_00" disabled="disabled" class="edit" onkeypress="return numberOnly(this, event)" title="You can only enter numbers upto 3 " maxlength="3" />


</div >

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "clone all of them"? There is already one form there

Comment: yes..need to clone 2 dropdowns and one textbox @HüseyinBABAL

Comment: why do you need ids? why don't use array notation on the names of the form elements, then process information server side as a nested array

Comment: @user3114651: could you be more clear on your requirement, its confusing.do you want to limit the no of dropdown list boxes and the test boxes to just 5  or is it something else ?

Comment: @dreamweiver: yes i need to limit it as well as assign different values at the same time...i tried using the demo given in the question but it does not apply to similar elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is your answer:

```
var counter = 1;

$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    if (counter <= 4) {
        counter++
        var innerCounter = 0;
        $('#elements').find(".innerDiv:last").clone().appendTo("#elements").find('select').each(function () {
            innerCounter++;
            $(this).attr({
                'name': 'ddl_' + counter + innerCounter,
                    'id': 'ddl_' + counter + innerCounter
            })
        }).next('input')
            .attr({
            'name': 'inText_' + counter,
                'id': 'inText_' + counter
        })
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/realdeepak/hGG3V/3/

Comment: only one issue with the code that is the div should be seen on 5 times  the counter goes on the click count.And secondly the div gets multiplied it should be cloned only once i.e it is getting multiplied from 1 to 2 and 2 to directly 4

Comment: check updated fiddle link with code. It will not create multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like;

```
var counter = 1;

$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
    if(counter <= 5)  {
     counter++
         var innerCounter = 0;
         $('table').find("tr:eq(1)").clone().appendTo("table").find('select').each(function() {
             innerCounter++;
             $(this).attr({
                   'name': 'ddl_' + counter + innerCounter,
                   'id'   : 'ddl_' + counter +innerCounter
               })
         }).closest('td').next('td').find('input')
               .attr({
                   'name': 'ddl_' + counter,
                   'id'   : 'ddl_' + counter
               })
    }
});
```

Here is a working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/UkzU3/3/**

Comment: This is what i used and worked but i am using 2 different select boxes and need different ids for both wherein,in this code both the select boxes get the same id

Comment: @user3114651 See updated answer and demo, I corrected a character

Comment: can u help me with the url of the fiddle so that i can show u my output to this

Comment: No i want to post my new url with fiddle so that u can check my code

Comment: You can update my fiddle with Update button on main menu

Comment: Why are you using `var id = current_id+1;
      current_id = id;` ?

Comment: to just increment the value,current_id ++ also works the same(was just checking both coz it was not changing my element id )

Comment: In your example, you are cloning elements to secodn div #elements. But this case is different. I need to change my implementation . Why didn't you use my current implementation?

Comment: i couldnt use your current implementation as i have used many tr tds in my code...i have a bigger form coz of which locating a specific tr and td would be difficult

Answer (score 0):

if your id code is working than check it solve,

//try this

```
var counter = 1;

$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
 counter+=1;
 if(counter <= 5)  {
$('table').find("tr:eq(1)").clone().appendTo("table").find('select')
        .attr({
               'name': 'ddl_' + counter,
               'id'   : 'ddl_' + counter
           })
           .closest('td').next('td').find('input')
           .attr({
               'name': 'ddl_' + counter,
               'id'   : 'ddl_' + counter
           })
}
});
```

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/UkzU3/1/)

Comment: i could increment the value as well as limit it but i cannot use this same code for two similar elements (eg: 2 dropdowns)